# Как правильно в простом сайте разделить логику и представление?

Tags: php

Как правильно в простом сайте разделить логику и представление?

Comment: Грань достаточно тонка. И это объяснить в большинстве случаев нельзя, это нужно понять.

Comment: Согласен, без предстваления сути истину не понять!

Comment: Вы уверены, что сайт прост, раз такой вопрос вообще возникает ?

Comment: Мне просто при приёме на работу задали сделать гостевую книгу. Нужно было сделать только возможность добавления, удаления и редактирования записей. Я сделал это всё компактно почти в одном файле. 
Когда посмотрели мою работу, то сказали, что нет разделения логики и представления а также не используется ООП. Вот у меня и встал вопрос, нужно ли в элементарных вещях использовать разделение логики. Кстати по поводу ООП тоже стало интересно. Я думал что в такой работе нет смысла использовать ООП.

Comment: Нужно, в первую очередь, ТЗ. Где будут прописаны и требования к функционалу и требования ко внешнему виду, и требования к архитектуре, и, если они есть — требования к коду. При собеседовании, конечно, можно все проделать не письменно, а устно, но задание должно быть явно детальнее «сделай нам гостевушку». Пожалуй, при собеседовании стоило задать вопрос «а что вы хотите получить, и на что хотите посмотреть?»

А ООП и прочее — это уже вопрос вторичный. Есть у заказчика требования или пожелания по архитектуре — тогда имеет значение. Нет — тогда все определяется только, эээ, мнением разработчика.

Answer (score 3):

[[@dima-opr](/users/6263/dima-opr)](/users/6263/dima-opr). Прочитал Ваш комментарий и понял о чем речь.

Вы правы, но со своей стороны. Работодатель же хотел понять (оценить) другое.

Не помню кто (Ф. Брукс ?), написал, что программы делятся на 3 типа. *Зубочистка* (пишем, используем, выбрасываем). *Молоток* (пишем, долго используем, не меняем). *Небоскреб* (пишем, используем, изменяем, используем, изменяем ...).

От Вас хотели маааленький небоскребчик (это для его жизненного цикла важно ООП и модные шаблоны проектирования), а Вы им молоточек (или зубочистку).

Comment: Ну тут работодатель не прав. Нужно было четко поставить задачу, используя ООП или нет. Задание дали, он сделал, работает, в чем проблема то? А если бы он использовал ООП или фрэймворки, то они сказали бы, зачем мол в простых вещах Вы тянете целый фрэймворк? Словом, работодатель тут странный, я считаю, если он хотел извратиться, надо было сказать.

Comment: Наверное вообще сначала надо посмотреть в глаза работодателю, а потом (если отвращения к нему не возникло) обсуждать, что  и с какой целью писать.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ скорее не на вопрос а на последний комментарий ТСа - разделять логику нужно в любом случае, сегодня у вас 20 строк элементарного когда, завтра 50, послезавтра 100500 строк быдлокода =)

Вот что касается ООП я, все-таки, считаю что ООП, безусловно, помогает делать более человеко-читаемым и расширяемым, помогает организовать логику, но тут ключевое слово **помогает**, помогает, но не организовывает. Таким образом грамотный программист напишет хороший, расширяемый код и при использовании функционального подхода, плохой такого кода не напишет никогда, не с использованием ООП, ни без.

Я это к тому что это не панацея, хотя, конечно-же, на работе ООП может быть очень важным (или банально необходимым) т.к., например, PHP фреймворки построены с приминением ООП, да и, если речь о большом проэкте или просто о работе в команде, ООП всетаки друг и товарищ в разделении обязаностей программистов. На всякий случае еще раз повторюсь - помощник, но не волшебная палочка =)

Comment: А еще понадобятся тесты (TDD ведь наше все), профайлинг, возможности по масштабированию, документация (и разработчика и пользователя), пакетирование для удобства деплоймента и так далее и так далее, см. любой длинный список best practices. Ход мыслей понимаете?

И, в итоге, таким легким движением мысли, задача по созданию гостевушки на «покажи-и-выброси» (пол-часа с перерывом на чай) переходит в работу по созданию сферической системы в вакууме, которой можно заниматься очень долго.

Только, все же, вопрос — «а надо ли?» — стоит поднять заранее, до того, как принимается за работу.

Comment: @drdaeman - к чему такие крайности?

О да, без TDD написать гостевую никак, вы что не в настроении проснулись? :DDD

Answer (score 0):

Почитать в сторону MVC: [MVC для начинающих](http://chtivo.webhost.ru/articles/mvc.php).

Comment: Мне кто-то говорил, что MVC используется только для движков и больших сайтов. Или для самых простых он тоже подойдёт?

Comment: Да, вполне. MVC это просто подход (паттерн) к программированию. То есть в случае разделения модели и контроллера, постараться что-бы все sql запросы были в одном месте, а обращение к базе данных шло через некие методы (функции) модели.

Comment: MVC можно, и даже нужно, использовать в большинстве проектов. Мелкие 3-х страничные сайты - не исключение. Смотрите в сторону микрофреймворков.

Comment: @Drakmail а зачем смотреть в или на... если недолго написать свой?

Comment: и вообще самый достойный ответ хоть и в комментарри, это от @shurik!

Comment: @shurik в самом деле прав. Более того грань не просто тонка, она еще и у всех разная.

Comment: Pavleman: согласен, написать свой (может даже и не микро) фреймворк - на мой взгляд, наилучший способ понять, как правильно надо работать с другими фреймворками. Правда, этот способ требует больше времени, чем просто использование готового фреймворка, и подходит, если в будущем действительно будет интересно всем этим заниматься.

PS. А как тут ники выделять в ответе?

Comment: @Drakmail перед ником ставить `@` без пробелов и без ошибок типа **Pavleman**

Comment: Фасады рулят, а MVC я видел в джумле) Let the holy war start!))